# Windows Phone MessageBox that looks like bubble popup

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone

I need a message box like control that looks like a bubbling popup. Like the speech bubble message from the phone.

Can someone recommend such control? How can I achieve this effect in Windows Phone?

Answer (score 1):

Check out the Coding4Fun windows phone toolkit. They have chatbubble controls that you can easily add to your project. They also have prompt controls that notify users of events that you specify. coding4fun.codeplex.com